Movie about people living on spaceship, but unaware it's a ship
Some people found a big spaceship. When they go inside, they find that there are people living inside a big dome. The people thought that they were living on a planet and didn't know that they were living inside a big dome inside a spaceship.
I'm fairly sure that I watched it around 2010-2015, but it could have been released earlier than that.

Any more details? That's a fairly common theme in SF. For example, did it look like an old movie, or a recent one when you saw it?

Was there just the one dome, or a few, or many of them?  What level of technology did the dome dwellers have?  What was their society like?  How were they dressed?  How many visitors were there?  How did they get there?  (Transporter vs. shuttle, for instance)  Were the visitors wearing uniforms?

there was a Star Trek episode For the World is Hollow and I Have Touched the Sky

Some similarities to The Starlost, but wrong timeframe. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Starlost

@FlaStorm32 The Starlost was my immediate thought, especially since some of the episodes were recut into TV movies.  But it's always pretty clear there are multiple domes, not just one

Although this description might fit any number of sci-fi shows, at first blush, this reminds me of The Orville, specifically the season 1 episode "If the Stars Should Appear", which first aired on September 28, 2017.
From Wikipedia's synopsis of this episode:

The Orville encounters an immense, 2,000-year-old derelict ship
drifting into a star. Mercer, Grayson, Kitan, Finn, and Isaac enter,
discovering an artificial biosphere and a civilization of three
million who worship an entity called Dorahl. They are unaware they are
on a ship. Grayson is held prisoner by their theocratic dictator,
Hamelac, who imposes a death penalty on "Reformers" who believe
anything exists beyond their known world.

So:

People living inside a spaceship? Check.
Unaware that they're in a spaceship? Check.
Under a big dome? Check. At the end of the episode, the Orville's crew repairs the ship, shuts off the permanent day-cycle environment, and shows the panorama of stars in the giant dome above.
Timeframe? Pretty close. 2017 is near enough to 2015 that it is reasonable.
Movie? No, but given the lack of certainty presented in the question, I am giving the "movie" portion some leeway. :)

Was this, perhaps, what you saw?

This has to be it. It's too close to a perfect match for what they are asking about.

In case you have some of the details slightly off, the time-frame matches and the plot you described resembles the SyFy miniseries Ascension:

The story takes place aboard a generation ship launched in the 1960s and now half-way into its 100-year journey to Proxima Centauri. A murder on board sparks off a series of events that leads some of the crew to begin second-guessing their real mission.

Which, unfortunately, was canceled before any conclusion was filmed.

Ascension has the reverse of this plot. In Ascension people are actually on a planet but think they are on a spaceship. Instead of being unaware they are on a ship, they are unaware they are on earth.

Dark City? No dome enclosure, though.

I did post this in the comments but then thought it so far off i deleted it. There is a dome enclosure though, its sort of thinly seen as encompassing the top half, that you only see towards the end with the reveal. But yes, perhaps not so obvious.

Yes, I considered that the force field might be a dome, but I figure dark city isn't it because nobody entered the city from outside.
